# How to validate request content for web service?

Tags: security, nginx, haproxy, gateway

I would like to find the generic way to validate HTTP request content before it's reached the server.

The goal is to provide robust security for the product.

I have an API exposed to the public, and I want to filter requests to my API by any proxy which allow following rules.

For example one of my API method:

```
POST: my_server/data/colection
application/json

{
    "key1": "stringValue",
    "key2": 2,
    "key3": true
}
```

I want to validate following facts:

- the request body is valid JSON object
- "key1" is a string, required, allow [a-z,0-9], max length 50 characters.
- "key2" is number, required, in the range of 1-1000
- "key3" is boolean, optional

If a content or schema of the request not fit criteria above I want to reject the request with appropriate status code.

Is there is any service or proxy module (nginx, haproxy or any other) which allow to do such things?

P.S. Even partial solution might work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical functionality for web application firewalls (wafs). There are quite a few on the market and I don't want to advertise any of them, but most can do this along with other nice security features (like filtering out potential attacks based on their internal rules, or gathering and sharing threat intelligence across the internet).

Three things to consider with a waf are the relatively high price tag, the effort needed to properly set it up, and the fact that they are not perfect, ie. while they may protect against say XSS to some extent, if the protected application is vulnerable, there will most probably be a way around the filters in the waf. But it does raise the bar.

I'm not very familiar with api gateways, but I suspect some of those may also offer this parameter type and range enforcement functionality (without the other aspects of protection provided by a full waf).